# Não é possivel exibir strings com quebra de linha em Node.js

Tags: node.js

Preciso trabalhar com css em um script js para o nodejs.
Porem se o css tem alguma quebra de linha o console.log não funciona.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync('style.css').toString();
console.log(contents);
```

Porem seu eu tirar os espaços da para ver que foi carregado o conteudo:

```
console.log(contents.replace(/\s/g, "\r"););
```

O problema é que preciso exibir com todas as quebras de linhas no meu projeto.

Estou inciando no Nodejs. Se alguém puder me explicar porque isso e como resolver.

Estou executando o nodeJS dentro do exec do php:

```
$exec = exec($nodejs." p.js ", $output);

echo $exec;
```

Comment: Mostra aí o ficheiro css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6uLjr37o/

Comment: O seu código funciona correctamente na minha máquina veja na imagem https://imagebin.ca/v/4932HMtdCHdt

Comment: Estou usando dentro de um exec no php em sistema Windows, será esse o problema?

Comment: Acabei de testar em sistema linux debian 9 no meu servidor e não funciona também.

Comment: Vou testar em Linux

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muitos testes descobri que cada quebra de linha no php é recebido pelo $output como um array.

o echo no $exec só pega a ultima quebra de linha.

Desta forma para exibir o conteúdo foi só usar um foreach!

```
$exec = exec($nodejs." p.js ", $output);

foreach($output as $line){ echo $line."\n";}
```